# How to set a proxy for WKWebView?

Tags: ios, swift, nsurlsession, wkwebview, nsurlrequest

I'm using `WKWebView` to open web page, now I need set a proxy for a specific `URL`.
I know how to send a request with proxy, just use `URLSession` like the following.

```
let proxyHost = "1.2.3.4"
let proxyPort = 9000
let proxyConfiguration = URLSessionConfiguration.default
proxyConfiguration.connectionProxyDictionary = [
            kCFNetworkProxiesHTTPEnable: true,
            kCFNetworkProxiesHTTPProxy: proxyHost,
            kCFNetworkProxiesHTTPPort: proxyPort,
]
let session = URLSession(configuration: proxyConfiguration)
```

But there is no API of `WKWebView` can receive `URLSession` or something like proxy configuration.
Dose anyone know how to do it?
Thanks in advance.